# Swapping rows in Gauss Jordan method

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Suppose in Gauss Elimination Method the first value of matrix, A[0][0]=0

Then how can I swap row 1 of matrix "A" with row 2, so that i get the correct result ?

Comment: Why don't you... swap them ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming a simpel 2d-array build the way as shown below: just exchange the rows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define S_MATRIX_DIM 5

int main()
{

  int **A;
  int *tmp;
  int i, j, entry;

  entry = 0;
  A = malloc(S_MATRIX_DIM * sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < S_MATRIX_DIM; i++) {
    A[i] = malloc(S_MATRIX_DIM * sizeof(int));
    for (j = 0; j < S_MATRIX_DIM; j++) {
      A[i][j] = entry++;
    }
  }

  puts("Matrix A =");
  for (i = 0; i < S_MATRIX_DIM; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < S_MATRIX_DIM; j++) {
      printf("%d,", A[i][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }

  tmp = A[0];
  A[0] = A[1];
  A[1] = tmp;

  puts("Matrix A, row exchanged =");
  for (i = 0; i < S_MATRIX_DIM; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < S_MATRIX_DIM; j++) {
      printf("%d,", A[i][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }

  for (i = 0; i < S_MATRIX_DIM; i++) {
    free(A[i]);
  }
  free(A);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

keep a temp value from the same type;
swap value by value,
example:

```
temp=a[i][j];
a[i][j]=a[i+1][j];
a[i+1][j]=temp;
```